# how can I make this work? (plotly-python)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I've reached a point where I don't know what else to do.

I have this df

```
dff8df      !!!0 WWSF   VPIP   VPIP   VPIP
0         52.0  38.64  38.64  38.64
1         62.0  50.00  50.00  50.00
2         73.0  56.25  56.25  56.25
3         99.0  23.08  23.08  23.08
4         30.0  41.67  41.67  41.67
..         ...    ...    ...    ...
540       50.0  18.75  18.75  18.75
541       99.0  26.32  26.32  26.32
542       50.0  28.57  28.57  28.57
543       83.0  14.29  14.29  14.29
544       57.0  38.89  38.89  38.89

[545 rows x 4 columns]
```

and this code:

```
print("dff8df",dff8)

    figure = px.scatter(data_frame=dff8,
                   x=dff8[:,drop1],
                   y=dff8[:,drop2],
                   color=dff8[:,drop4],
                   size=dff8[:,drop3],
                   trendline="ols",
                   trendline_color_override="red",
                   title="%s vs %s"%(drop1, drop2),
                   )
```

and it gives this error with plotly in python:

```
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), 'VPIP')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of areas to consider

- this is a **pandas** error not a **plotly** error
- you have not defined `drop1` etc so I can only assume you mean them to be column names.  Hence have defined as first four columns of your sample data
- your sample data looks problematic,  multiple columns with name **VPIP** the data frame created from `read_csv()`

| dff8df | !!!0 | WWSF | VPIP | VPIP.1 | VPIP.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 52 | 38.64 | 38.64 | 38.64 | nan |
| 1 | 62 | 50 | 50 | 50 | nan |
| 2 | 73 | 56.25 | 56.25 | 56.25 | nan |
| 3 | 99 | 23.08 | 23.08 | 23.08 | nan |

- `dff8[:,drop1]` is invalid **pandas** code to select a column.  This should be `dff8.loc[:, drop1]`.  Additionally why so slice in this way when you can just pass column names to **plotly express**

#### working code

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

dff8 = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """dff8df      !!!0 WWSF   VPIP   VPIP   VPIP
0         52.0  38.64  38.64  38.64
1         62.0  50.00  50.00  50.00
2         73.0  56.25  56.25  56.25
3         99.0  23.08  23.08  23.08
4         30.0  41.67  41.67  41.67
540       50.0  18.75  18.75  18.75
541       99.0  26.32  26.32  26.32
542       50.0  28.57  28.57  28.57
543       83.0  14.29  14.29  14.29
544       57.0  38.89  38.89  38.89"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
    index_col=0,
)

drop1, drop2, drop3, drop4 = dff8.columns[0:4].tolist()

figure = px.scatter(
    data_frame=dff8,
    x=dff8.loc[:, drop1],
    y=dff8.loc[:, drop2],
    color=dff8.loc[:, drop4],
    size=dff8.loc[:, drop3],
    trendline="ols",
    trendline_color_override="red",
    title="%s vs %s" % (drop1, drop2),
)


figure
```

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm doing another graph in the same dashboard, only one variable, but gives me KeyError: 0 is it because of drop1 = dfff3.columns[0:1].tolist()  (is there something wrong with this?

Comment: what is `drop1`? an argument to a **callback** that is the value of a dropdown? as I stated in answer,  it's not clear why you are deciding to slice your dataframe in this unique way rather that just pass column names rather than **pandas** series to `px.scatter()`. I would expect `px.scatter(dfff3, y=drop1)` would work and be far simpler to code and avoid coding errors...  the reason `drop1, drop2, drop3, drop4 = dff8.columns[0:4].tolist()` is in the answer is because the question didn't specify what they are so I had to initialise them to something...

Comment: the drop is an argument to a callback

Comment: then just go with the simple normal way to use **plotly express**. Use all the convenience capabilities of high level API

Comment: yes .... I changed the comment coz I did that after. anyway thanks